# Ist "Zu Geschäftsjahresbeginn" korrekt?

Tags: grammaticality, nominalization

Ich bin über einen Satz gestolpert, der mit `Zu Geschäftsjahresbeginn werden` losging, was sich in meinen Ohren erstmal komisch angehört hat.

Ich persönlich hätte das als `Zum Geschäftsjahresbeginn werden` formuliert.

Aber gleichzeitig hört es sich für mich komisch an, wenn jemand `Zum Beginn werden` sagen würde.

Macht es einen Unterschied, ob `Beginn` Teil eines Kompositums ist um sich für `zu` oder `zum` zu entscheiden?

Comment: Muttersprachliches Bauchgefühl sagt "ja, macht einen Unterschied", aber ich kann's noch nicht recht in Worte fassen...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Zu Geschäftsjahresbeginn* ist für mich **jeder** Beginn eines Geschäftsjahres (heute, nächstes Jahr, in zehn Jahren immer noch) - Das wird über den fehlenden Artikel ausgedrückt. Es geht also um einen *jährlichen Termin*.

*Zum Geschäftsjahresbeginn* verwendet einen bestimmten Artikel, meint also den Beginn eines bestimmten Geschäftsjahres. Es gilt nicht notwendigerweise allgemein für alle Geschäftsjahre (außer der Kontext sagt was anderes wie "Jedes Jahr zum Geschäftsjahresbeginn...").

Mit Kompositum oder nichts hat das wenig zu tun - bei

> Zu Beginn eines Jahres...

bzw.

> Zum Beginn eines Jahres...

würde ich das genauso sehen.

Comment: Vom Gefühl her denke ich ähnlich. Jedoch dürfte die Bedeutung eigentlich die Gleiche sein.